# What is equivalent to IsExperienceEditor in the ASP.NET Core SDK?

Tags: rendering-host

In ASP.NET Core Rendering Host, I would like to hide something if the page is not in Experience Editor mode, with something like `Sitecore.Context.PageMode.IsExperienceEditor` in ASP.NET. Is it possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems that the originally accepted answer is no longer true. Adding the `ISitecoreRenderingContext` to DI in `startup.cs` as described in step 1 does allow `ISitecoreRenderingContext` to be injected into views/class, but it contains only NULL for all values.

Instead, inject the `IHttpContextAccessor` into your view/class and use the following code to get the same result:

```
@inject IHttpContextAccessor HttpContextAccessor
if (HttpContextAccessor.HttpContext?.GetSitecoreRenderingContext()?.Response?.Content?.Sitecore?.Context?.IsEditing ?? false)
{
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 5):

It is possible by using `ISitecoreRenderingContext`. Although it's not a static class anymore, so you need to add to your DI container and inject it to your class and/or view.

**1. `Startup.cs`:**

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    ...
    services.AddScoped<ISitecoreRenderingContext, SitecoreRenderingContext>();
    ...
}
```

**2/a. In a view:**

```
@inject ISitecoreRenderingContext SitecoreContext
if (SitecoreContext.Response?.Content?.Sitecore?.Context?.IsEditing ?? false)
{
    ...
}
```

**2/b. in a class:**

```
private readonly ISitecoreRenderingContext _sitecoreContext;
    
public YourClass(ISitecoreRenderingContext sitecoreContext)
{
    _sitecoreContext = sitecoreContext;
}

public void YourMethod()
{
    if (_sitecoreContext.Response?.Content?.Sitecore?.Context?.IsEditing ?? false)
    {
        ...
    }
}
```

If you need to distinguish between Edit/Preview/Normal then you can use `SitecoreContext.Response?.Content?.Sitecore?.Context?.PageState`, which represents all the 3 states.